# Implement random search algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, random, implementation

I'm tryin to implement a simple "random search algorithm" in Java

here's a piece of the code:

//execute the algorithm

```
    double bestSolution; //INITIAL SOLUTION!
    Vector bestVector=null;

    for (int iter=0; iter<maxIterations; iter++) {
        //generate random vector-solution
        Vector v = Vector.generateRandomVector(problemSize, minOfSearchSpace, maxOfSearchSpace);
        double currentObjValue = objectiveFunctionValue(v);
        // if a better solution is found
        if (currentObjValue < bestSolution); { 
            bestVector = v;
            bestSolution = currentObjValue;
        }
        System.out.println("Iteration: "+(iter+1)+" Best solution: "+bestSolution);
    } // end for

    System.out.println("\n\nBest solution: "+bestVector.toString()+" Objective Value: "+bestSolution);
```

my problem is: somehow i have to initialize the initial solution "double bestSolution".
what initial value should i give? note that for certain objective function, values such as "0" while make the convergence harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you're at the first iteration (`iter == 0`), and initialize the bestSolution with the computed solution if it's the first iteration, else compare it with the previous bestSolution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems natural to me to use

```
double bestSolution = Double.MAX_VALUE
```

since presumably your first guess will be the best so far, no matter what it is.

or maybe even

```
double bestSolution = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY
```

Comment: pretty reasonable idea but think of this example:

Comment: min x^2 using that initial value the algorithm will never converge

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are using the value of `bestSolution` as a seed for generating the next vector.  I must be missing something, does `generateRandomVector()` somehow use `bestSolution`?  As I understand it you're just generating random candidates, so the initial value shouldn't affect the result.

Comment: that's what exacty random search does. create random solutions using generateRandomVector() in a pre-specified search space and comparees with the pevious best solution.

Comment: in that case the solution will not converge any faster no matter what your initial choice of `bestSolution` is.

Comment: that's right it will not converge any faster. 
but if the initial solution is "bad" it will definetly converge slowly.

anyway, random search is a too primitive algorithm and doesn't deserve any further analysis :P